# Using database information in droplist laravel 4

Tags: laravel

I had followed this tutorial:

// Many of you may know this already, but for those who don't this is really handy for building dropdowns

```
// Suppose you want to show a categories dropdown whose information is pulled from an Eloquent model
// You can use the query builder's "lists" method (available for Eloquent as any query builder method) which
// returns an associative array you can pass to the Form::select method

$categories = Category::lists('title', 'id');

// note that the parameters you pass to lists correspond to the columns for the value and id, respectively
// in this case, "title" and "id"

// you should pass this data to your view and then build the dropdown inside it


//somewhere in your view
{{ Form::select('category', $categories) }}
```

Now, I got everything working,but I got one problem. Instead of returning the Name, it returns the number of the drop down list..

in userscontroller:

```
public function postCreatelist() {
    $userid = Auth::user()->id;
    $animename = Input::get('listname');
    $episodesseen = Input::get('episodes');
    User::find($userid)->episodes()->insert(array(
    'name' => $animename,
    'author_id' => $userid,
    'episodeswatched' => $episodesseen
    ));
    return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', 'Added anime to list');
}
public function getAddlist() {
    $list = DB::table('animes')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
    $listname = Animes::lists('name');

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.addlist', array('list'=>$list, 'listname'=>$listname));
}
```

View:

```
{{ Form::select('listname', $listname) }}
```

So, I need to return the name, but it returns the number of the dropdownlist. So if I pick the first option it returns 0. Second option returns 1. But it should return the names..

I hope I explained it clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the second parameter because that is the key of the results array.

```
$categories = Category::lists('title', 'title');
```